# Why are flares known as bengalas in Spanish?

Tags: etimología

Is there a specific reason flares/similar pyrotechnics are named after Bengal? The RAE says only:

> [**bengala**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=bengala)
>   Del port. *bengala*, y este del persa *bangāle* 'Bengala', provincia del Indostán.

And [**luz de bengala**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=NkAteAU#MVjQP5I) contains no further information.

Comment: Curiosamente, en portugués moderno *[bengala](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bengala)* significa "bastón", vaya uno a saber por qué.

Comment: @pablodf76 Vi esto antes, puede ser de interés: [*En diálogo, Volume 1*, Jorge Luis Borges, Osvaldo Ferrari](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rL07ZtS2RAsC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=cañas%20bengala%20portugués) (p.53)

Comment: "...y con cañas. ¡Ah! bueno, yo estuve hace poco en Brasil, y redescubrí algo que me había sido revelado ya por las novelas de Eça de Queiroz, que **es el nombre que tiene el bastón en portugués. Se llama "bengala" —sin duda por las cañas de Bengala—;** porque alguien me dijo: "A sua bengala", me tendió mi bastón, que es irlandés, y yo recordé aquella palabra (*rie*), me pareció muy lindo que el bastón se llamara "bengala". Porque "bastón" no recuerda nada especialmente. Bueno, ¿qué puede recordar?, los bastos: es un basto grande, es un gran as de basto..."

Comment: "... En cambio, "bengala" ya nos trae toda una región, y el bengalí la palabra "bungalow", derivada de "bengala" también."

Comment: Creo que fue precisamente leyendo a Eça de Queiroz que conocí esta palabra en portugués (¡parece como que todos los hombres de cierta posición social usan un bastón como accesorio!).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/technology/Bengal-light) says of *blue light* (the precursor to modern signalling flares):

> The flare in its present form dates from the early part of the 19th century, when the introduction of potassium chlorate permitted the development of chemical mixtures to produce coloured light. Previous to this the only colour had been the bluish white light produced by a mixture of sulfur, saltpetre, and orpiment. These blue lights, as they were called, were and still are often used at sea for signaling and illumination. **They were also known as Bengal lights, probably because Bengal was the chief source of saltpetre.**

Wikipedia also claims [Bengal fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_light_(pyrotechnic_signal)#Decline) is an old synonym for Bengal lights/blue light.

It seems likely that the Spanish word has the same origin, as indeed [etimologias.dechile.net](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?bengala) suggests:

> La palabra **Bengala** es un topónimo de una provincia en el noreste de la India. Hoy forma parte de India y Bangladesh. Esta provincia fue descubierta por Marco Polo (1254-1324), quien la nombró así por Banga, nombre de un jeque y su tribu que vivía en esa zona. **Aparte de esa gente y los famosos tigres, ahí producían un fuego artificial de color azul, quemando una mezcla de azufre, salitre y orpimento. Este era un fuego muy vivo y los marineros lo empezaron a usar para hacer señales. De ahí el término "luz de bengala".**